# Add XML child after empty child

Tags: php, simplexml

I want to create an XML document from the object page, that contains some information about a print page. I am using this code:

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<page/>');
$xml->addChild( "pageid", $page->id );
$xml->addChild( "keyword", $page->page_name );

$elements = $xml->addChild( "elements" );

foreach ( $page->elements as $page_element ) {
    $element = $elements->addChild( "element" );
    $element->addChild( "type", $page_element["type"] );
    $element->addChild( "id", $page_element["id"] );
    $element->addChild( "parentContainerID", $page_element["parent_container_id"] );
    $element->addChild( "parentContainerType", $page_element["parent_container_type"] );
    $element->addChild( "Width", $page_element["width"] ?? 0 );
    $element->addChild( "Height", $page_element["height"] ?? 0 );
    $user_def_fields = $element->addChild( "UserDefFields" );

    if ( isset( $page_element["custom_fields"] ) ) {
            foreach ( $page["custom_fields"] as $custom_field_name => $custom_field_value ) {
                $user_def_field = $user_def_fields->addChild( "field" );
                $user_def_field->addChild( "label", $custom_field_name );
                $user_def_field->addChild( "value", $custom_field_value );
            }                        
        }
    }

    $states = $element->addChild( "ArticleStates" );

    foreach( $page_element["article_states"] as $state ) {
        $states->addChild( "articlestate", $state );
    }
}
```

This works - but when article_states is empty, I get this:

```
<element>
  <type>group</type>
  <id>1234</id>
  <parentcontainerid>2345</parentcontainerid>
  <parentcontainertype>article</parentcontainertype>
  <width>0</width>
  <height>0</height>
  <userdeffields>
    <articlestates></articlestates>
  </userdeffields>
</element>
```

The articlesstates tag is inside the userdeffields. That's wrong, it should be like this:

```
<element>
  <type>group</type>
  <id>1234</id>
  <parentcontainerid>2345</parentcontainerid>
  <parentcontainertype>article</parentcontainertype>
  <width>0</width>
  <height>0</height>
  <userdeffields></userdeffields>
  <articlestates></articlestates>      
</element>
```

H

Comment: I don’t see how whether `$page_element["article_states"]` is empty or not could have anything to do with that ... adding the `articlestates` element happens before this property is even looped over. Can you show a working example that reproduces this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple... but strange indeed.
Just add a space like this:

```
$user_def_fields = $element->addChild( "UserDefFields", " " );
```

I just have to remember to use the trim function when parsing the XML... JSON ftw :-)

Comment: Please respond to @CBroe above. The line `$states = $element->addChild("ArticleStates")` occurring outside of any loop clearly suggests `<ArticleStates>` must output as a child to `<element>` and **not** `<userdeffields>`. Your posted example does not align to code as can be seen with the capital camel case in code but not in XML and XML is case-sensitive.